# Paperclip saving the image outside the :rails_root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, image-uploading

Hi am using **paperclip** for image upload, problem is i want to access the image for **two application** deployed in the same server, for that i have to save the image in common folder outside of rails root. how can i do this?

Help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip under this got to Understanding Storage. You can specify path to whatever folder you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by two ways:

1) config/application.rb or in any of the config/environments/*.rb files

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Other code...

    config.paperclip_defaults = {:storage => :fog, :fog_credentials => {:provider => "Local", :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public"}, :fog_directory => "", :fog_host => "localhost"}
  end
end
```

2) Rails initializer:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :fog
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_credentials] = {:provider => "Local", :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public"}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_directory] = ""
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:fog_host] = "http://localhost:3000"
```